# Angular UI datepicker popup on button not showing after 1st time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Html:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openCalendar($event)" ng-model="currentDate" ng-change="dateChanged(currentDate)" datepicker-popup
                        show-button-bar="false" is-open="calendarOpened">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    {{currentDate | date}}
                </button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.openCalendar = function ($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();
            $scope.calendarOpened = true;
        };
```

The thing is, the *$scope.openCalendar* is called just fine, however the popup does not shown after the **first time**.
It's like *$scope.calendarOpened = true* didn't trigger the popup.

Any ideas? How can I debug or figure out why it is not working?

Comment: Try using is-open="$parent.calendarOpened" and see if that helps

Comment: It worked! Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug in the implementation of the datepicker with regards to scope, or intended that way. There are a few discussions about it if you search around.

Comment: I think there is something wrong, because there is another issue: that ng-change="dateChanged(currentDate)", in that method, if I access $scope.currentDate, the value is the old date and not the new one; however, the parameter "currentDate" is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
  is-open="$parent.calendarOpened"
```